# pg_notify not sending payload text while using Npgsql inside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, npgsql

This is what I am doing.

In my PostgreSQL database, When an INSERT is made into my table, I trigger the pg_notify with a payload. Here is the script:

This is the trigger-

```
CREATE TRIGGER transactions_insert__trigger
AFTER INSERT
   ON transactions.transactions
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dashboard.notify_transaction_insert();
```

and here is the function-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard.notify_transaction_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('transaction_watcher', (NEW.tran_id||'%|%'||NEW.teller_id)::text);
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now inside Visual Studio, I have this Code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        connectionStringBuilder.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
        connectionStringBuilder.Database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
        connectionStringBuilder.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        connectionStringBuilder.SyncNotification = true;
        connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionLifeTime = int.MaxValue;
        connectionStringBuilder.CommandTimeout = 120;
        connectionStringBuilder.Pooling = true;


        _connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

        _connection.Open();


        var command = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN \"transaction_watcher\";", _connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _connection.Notification += new NotificationEventHandler(HandleNotification);
    }

  private static void HandleNotification(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayNotifications(e.AdditionalInformation);

    }
```

Now , This is all fine, the code is working. When I make an `INSERT` into the table, the NotificationEventHandler is getting fired in Visual Studio whether the `INSERT` is being done from inside the application or by using backend Query.

But the problem is I am only able to get the payload text when I make an `INSERT` from backend Query. When and `INSERT` is made while debugging the aplication using Visual Studio the Notification is being handled but I am getting emptyspace in the payload. I tried everything but could not manage to find the cause.

Can anyone kindly help me with this? Thanks in advance.